# Getting undefined property from Ajax response nested object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following ajax response from the API:

```
  {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 16,
      "sender_id": 1,
      "text": "Test",
      "created_at": "2017-07-21 15:42:08",
      "updated_at": "2017-07-21 15:42:08",
      "sender": {
        "data": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "John Doe",
          "email": "john@doe.co",
          "mobile": "+1875446799976",
          "photo_url": "https://example.co/storage/profiles/0H6Rkwsrlns0R1PY03Mta2qIhdPhV7N19jaagH3m.jpeg",
          "first_login": 0,
          "uses_two_factor_auth": false,
          "two_factor_reset_code": null,
          "current_team_id": 1,
          "stripe_id": null,
          "current_billing_plan": null,
          "billing_state": null,
          "vat_id": null,
          "trial_ends_at": "2017-06-27 10:06:05",
          "last_read_announcements_at": "2017-06-27 10:06:05",
          "created_at": "2017-06-27 10:06:05",
          "updated_at": "2017-06-28 10:40:07",
          "tax_rate": 0
        }
      },
      "buildings": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "team_id": 1,
            "name": "Oasis",
            "created_at": "2017-06-30 13:15:30",
            "updated_at": "2017-06-30 13:15:30",
            "pivot": {
              "sending_id": 16,
              "building_id": 4
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "messages": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 316,
            "sending_id": 16,
            "recipient_id": 42,
            "provider_id": "0B0000006A1ABFEF",
            "info": null,
            "status": "delivered",
            "price": "0.07500000",
            "error_text": null,
            "created_at": "2017-07-21 15:42:08",
            "updated_at": "2017-07-21 15:42:21",
            "recipient": {
              "id": 42,
              "name": "John Doe",
              "email": "john@doe.co",
              "mobile": "198765456789",
              "types": [
                "Inhabitant"
              ],
              "building_id": 4,
              "created_at": "2017-07-01 07:21:52",
              "updated_at": "2017-07-01 07:21:52",
              "deleted_at": null
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
    }
```

But when I try to display recipient name like the following:

```
<tr v-for="sending in sendings">
    <td>{{ sending.created_at | moment }}</td>
    <td><div style="width: 300px">{{ sending.text }}</div></td>
    <td>
        <div v-for="building in sending.buildings.data" v-if="sending.buildings.data">
            {{ building.name }}
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="message in sending.messages.data" v-if="sending.messages.data">
                {{ message.recipient.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I get this error in console and no row is display at all:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Here is the API call & callback:

```
getSendings() {
    axios.get('/api/v1/sendings', {
            params: {
                search: (this.searchSendings ? this.searchSendings.text : ''),
                limit: this.sendings ? (this.sendings.length + 10) : 10,
                building_id: this.selectedBuildingsIds
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.data.length) {
                this.sendings = response.data.data;

                if (response.data.meta.pagination.total_pages == 1) {
                    this.$refs.infiniteLoading.$emit('$InfiniteLoading:complete');
                } else {
                    this.$refs.infiniteLoading.$emit('$InfiniteLoading:loaded');
                }
            } else {
                this.$refs.infiniteLoading.$emit('$InfiniteLoading:complete');
            }
        });
},
```

This is data:

```
data() {
    return {
        sendings: null,
        selectedBuildings: null,
        selectedBuildingsIds: [],
        searchSendings: {
            text: null
        },
    };
},
```

It's odd because displaying Building name works just fine, the only difference is recipient is one level deeper..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the API call and callback please?

Comment: Does `sendings` exist in `data` *before* your callback?

Comment: No, you think it's needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I expect is causing the error is for some individual `message`, `message.recipient` is undefined. In the case that a `recipient` is undefined, when you try to access the `name` property of the recipient as you do here,

```
{{message.recipient.name}}
```

Javascript will throw an error because you are now trying to get the name property of undefined.

You can protect yourself against that error using a guard.

```
{{message.recipient && message.recipient.name}}
```

Comment: Well, sendings was actually in data set to empty array: []. I tried with null but no luck either. I added data in question.

Comment: @maunoxyd I [don't see the issue](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vJBXqj?editors=1010) then, based on what you have shown. Is it possible one of the buildings or recipients *doesn't* have a name?

Comment: Indeed, one recipient didn't exist anymore, and using the guard worked!